# Send a variable to a variable of a function?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function and one of the parameters is for the name of the target variable.. Would it be possible for me to send a variable to the function like this:

```
function otherfunction(input){
...
}

function test {target) {
var x = 1;
target(x);
}

test(otherfunction);
```

The problem I have is that I'm making a greasemonkey script and one of the variable I need can't be returned from the function due to a limitation.. So this would be the alternative. I just don't know how to get it to work.. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you be more precise on what your technical limitation actually is? The normal solution to your problem, as Jacob has outlined would be to call `otherfunction` within the body of `test`, but this inevitably results in calling `otherfunction()` anyway. So you may as well just write `otherfunction(1)` instead of `test(otherfunction)`.

Comment: @J. M Please accept correct answers to your questions by clicking inside the hollow checkmark. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your example (almost) works:

```
function otherfunction(input){
   alert(input);
}

function test(target) {
   if(typeof target !== 'function') {
      alert('target is not a function!');
      return;
   }
   target(1); //invokes the passed-in function, passing in 1
}

test(otherfunction); //alerts 1

//You can also do it with an anonymous function too:

test(function(arg) {
  alert(arg * 5);
}); //alerts 5
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NS8yC/)